# How would I construct a terminal command to download a folder with wget from a Media Temple (gs) server?

Tags: ftp, connection, wget, mediatemple

I'm trying to download a folder using wget on the Terminal (I'm usin a Mac if that matters) because my ftp client sucks and keeps timing out. It doesn't stay connected for long. So I was wondering if I could use wget to connect via ftp protocol to the server to download the directory in question. I have searched around in the internet for this and have attempted to write the command but it keeps failing. So assuming the following:

ftp username is: serveradmin@mydomain.ca
ftp host is:     ftp.s12345.gridserver.com
ftp password is:     somepassword

I have tried to write the command in the following ways:

```
wget -r ftp://serveradmin@mydomain.ca:somepassword@s12345.gridserver.com/path/to/desired/folder/

wget -r ftp://serveradmin:somepassword@s12345.gridserver.com/path/to/desired/folder/
```

When I try the first way I get this error:

```
 Bad port number.
```

When I try the second way I get a little further but I get this error:

```
Resolving s12345.gridserver.com... 71.46.226.79
Connecting to s12345.gridserver.com|71.46.226.79|:21... connected.
Logging in as serveradmin ... 
Login incorrect.
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scp` on the Mac instead, it will probably work much nicer.

`scp -r user@mediatemplehost.net:/folder/path /local/path`

Comment: Wow, I think it worked fairly nice! Thanks so much. 

Question: Do you think it worked because I had ssh access to the server? Would this work on other servers where I only have ftp access?

Comment: You need to have ssh access in order to use SCP. I don't think it would work if you only had FTP (I'm not 100% sure tho).

Make sure to mark your question as answered